# 500 Error When processing referenced script with params

Tags: javascript

I am dynamically adding reference files as such:

```
var jq = document.createElement("script");
jq.type = "text/javascript";
jq.src = "...abc.js?v=2.1.5";
document.body.appendChild(jq);
```

This however throws an internal 500 error. When I remove the v=2.1.5 parameter it loads fine. So do I add the parameter as an attribute?...or do I somehow pass it to the constructor?

Or leave it off and just not worry about getting the latest and greatest?

Thoughts?

Comment: you mean: `jq.type = "text/javascript"; jq.src = "...abc.js?v=2.1.5";`

Comment: yup typo! I'll fix now

Comment: Do you also get the error when browsing to it via the created url (I would expect that you do)? Is it possible that version 2.1.5 does not exist for that library?

Comment: @MichaelTodd Good question! Stand by...Yup...not loading. So the problem really isn't the parm but the version of the file it is looking for.

Comment: what is the script you're trying to load? 500 server error means the server that's trying to serve your request tanked for some reason. you're probably trying to reference a version of a script that doesn't exist. or, `v` is not a parameter name that the remote server expects ...

Comment: Is the script served by special server code or just the standard file system

Comment: Standard. The issue is as Michael Todd & Xander pointed out. It can't find the referenced file version and I know why.